# Display image in another activity after clicking on upload button

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to display my image to another activity after i clicked on the upload button. I have 2 activity (Main and Main2). Currently, I intent the uri to the next activity after selecting a image from gallery. How i intent the uri on my upload button instead?

**MainActivity.Java**

```
    private void uploadImage(){
        @Override
       public void onResponse(String s) {
           loading.dismiss();
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
           startActivity(i);
           finish();
       }
   },


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("imagepath", filePath.toString());
            startActivity(i);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Uri variable to a class level variable to store the uri result obtained from the `onActivityResult`

```
private Uri filePath;

 if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("imagepath", filePath.toString());
            startActivity(i);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and then in your button you can pass the Uri as:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("imagepath", filePath.toString());
            startActivity(i);
```

Comment: wow! thank you so much! It works but it still intent to the next activity when i select image from gallery which i dont want it to. However, i solved it by commenting/removing the startActivity(i) onActivityResult. Is it correct that i removed the startActivity to prevent it to intent to the next activity?

Comment: as a matter of fact it is. If you want that you proceed to the next activity by clicking the button only then startActivity(i) should be placed only in the onClick method of button.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help and please mark the answer as accepted so that if anyone else has the same problem they can benefit from it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as below:

define a class level variable:

```
   String filePathString = null;

private void uploadImage(){
 @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            },


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
            filePathString = filePath.toString();
            i.putExtra("imagepath", filePath.toString());
            startActivity(i);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And then set OnClickListener on your button:

```
uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent i = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
     i.putExtra("imagepath", MainActivity.this.filePathString);
     startActivity(i);
    MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are welcome, please vote the answer and accept it!!

Answer (score 1):

try this code
first put uri as string in intent.

```
intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
```

and then in second activity just convert back to string like this

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Uri filePath = data.getData();
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(filePath, projection, null, null,
                        null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
    Then pass selectedImagePath in the intent like below
    Intent i = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("imagepath", filePath.toString());
            startActivity(i);
```